# Android fragment scrolling all elements when using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android app. I am using `Fragment` and `RecyclerView`. In my screen have `SearchView`, header, `RecyclerView` and a `Button`. I want the screen like I have shown below image.

[image]

But it will scrolling all view. The bottom buttons are coming at the last of recyclerview last element. My layout code shown below.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:queryHint="Search Item" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lItemsHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@color/title_background">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item2"
                style="@style/ItemsHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:width="0dip"
                android:text="@string/caption_item"
                android:textColor="@color/background1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            androidrientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/title_background"
                android:text="Save &amp; Close"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to solve the problem? Please help me.

Comment: button is scrolling with the recycler view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:queryHint="Search Item" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lItemsHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
            android:background="@color/title_background">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item2"
                style="@style/ItemsHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"

                android:width="0dip"
                android:text="@string/caption_item"
                android:textColor="@color/background1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lItemsHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearFooter"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearFooter"
            androidrientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/title_background"
                android:text="Save &amp; Close"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout construction for the desired screen that you want is a bit complex. However, I would like to suggest you a simpler one. Try the layout I am proposing below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:queryHint="Search Item" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/title_winner"
        android:textColor="@color/segmented_button_text_color" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:paddingBottom="35dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Save and Close"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that, I have used a `paddingBottom` in your `RecyclerView` and added `clipToPadding` to true. So that the last item of your `RecyclerView` will not be hidden under the `Save and Close` button your have in the bottom of your screen.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search Item" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/lItemsHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:text="HEADER"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
             />




    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save &amp; Close"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<SearchView
android:id="@+id/search_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:queryHint="Search Item" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/lItemsHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:background="@color/title_background">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/item2"
style="@style/ItemsHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
android:width="0dip"
android:text="@string/caption_item"
android:textColor="@color/background1" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/linearFooter"
android:layout_below="@+id/lItemsHeader"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearFooter"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@color/title_background"
android:text="Save"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```